# Adding Real name to user profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, real-name

In the user profile there is a field to enter your real name (which is optional), but that field is never shown when visiting the user profile. I think it would be interesting as it can allow for a better user experience. I usually participate in C++ question and come across the same people to whom I still cannot refer by name, nor can they refer to me by name.

My proposal is leaving the rest of the system as it is, but adding the real name to the user profile. After all, the age does show and I think it is less interesting than the name.

Comment: related: [Why does the “Real Name” field not appear on the user profile page?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67331/146482)

Answer (score 5):

You can simply put your name in the About Me section.

Comment: It seems strange, nonetheless that I have entered my real name into a field that just disappears when I come out of the edit page.

Answer (score 5):

You could use your real name as your user handle. Works for me.

Comment: I have used my username so long in so many places that it identifies me almost as much as my real name. For the people that know me, that is. :) Also, using the real name: David Rodríguez Ibeas is longer for comments, and leads to misinterpretations (Rodríguez is not a middle name, but rather the first surname; and I had to fight with that problem for a long time...)

Comment: You need to get your self some hyphen action (kidding).